# android setLayerType crashing on lower version

Tags: android, canvas

I used the `setLayerType` method in my app to check the device `hardwareAccelerated` true or false, it's working on higher version (i.e 3+) but in lower version the app is crashing.

Here is my code snippet:

```
try {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
        view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }
} catch(Exception ex) {

}
```

I tried to check on AndroidManifest.xml but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Api level check you have set is wrong. Change to

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `setLayerType()` works only on **Api 11** and above. And **GINGERBREAD** is **Api 9** and **GINGERBREAD_MR1** is Api 10.